# Oracle Query to Sum up count from multiple tables

Tags: oracle

I need to take the count from multiple tables(1000+ Tables) and Sum up the same into a single value.

For example:  Tables starting with TA .. Only these tables needs to be considered.

I want the actual counts and hence dont want to use DBA_TABLES/ALL_TABLES.

Please suggest me the best way to do this. I just need the single value of Sum of all the records in those tables.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gobi.  You mentioned that you want actual counts, but since the first table's count might have changed by the time you count the 1000nth table, I'm interested in how badly the data dictionary stats are failing for you, since they are very convenient in this kind of situation.  Have you tried for example setting your `estimate_percent` to `100` (though not recommended for general stats-gathering) when gathering stats to increase rowcount accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE TA_1 AS select * FROM all_objects;
CREATE TABLE TA_2 AS select * FROM TA_1;
CREATE TABLE TA_abcd AS select * FROM TA_1;

select count(*) FROM TA_1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     73701
```

---

```
DECLARE
  partial_cnt NUMBER;
  final_cnt NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR tab_name IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'TA%' )
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM '|| tab_name.table_name INTO partial_cnt;
      final_cnt := final_cnt + partial_cnt;
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Total count = ' || final_cnt );
END;
/

Total count = 221103
```